# dropdown list with several times the same item

Tags: php, laravel

Below my drop-down list is not displaying correctly and I don't know where the problem is. Could it be in my SerieController? I want to create an edit/update system but I've had no success.

[image]

**SerielController**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $series = Serie::find($id);
        $marks = Mark::find($id);
        return view('admin.series.edit', compact('series', 'marks'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'fk_mark' => 'required'
        ]);

        $series = Serie::find($id);
        $marks = Mark::find($id);
        $series->name = $request->get('name');
        $series->fk_mark = $request->get('fk_mark');
        $series->save();
        return redirect()->route('series.index')
                   ->with('success', 'updated successfully');
    }
```

file **series.edit.blade**

```
<form class="panel-body" action="{{route('series.update',$series->id)}}" method="POST">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
@csrf
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label for="form-group-input-1">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$series->name}}">
</fieldset>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="company-content">Select Mark</label>
<select name="fk_mark" id="" class="form-control">
@foreach($series->marks as $mark)
<option value="{{$marks->id}}">
{{$marks->name_mark}}
</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

**Model Serie**

```
class Serie extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'fk_mark'];

    public function marks(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Mark', 'fk_mark');

    }

}
```

**Serie Mark**

```
class Mark extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name_mark'];

    public function series(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Serie', 'fk_mark');
    }


    public function cars(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Car','fk_serie');
   }

}
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your foreach you made a mistake, the variable should be `$mark` not `$marks`

```
<select name="fk_mark" id="" class="form-control">
   @foreach($marks as $mark)
   <option value="{{$mark->id}}">
   {{$mark->name_mark}}
   </option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

In your edit function you're sending just one Mark to your view, you need to send them all if you want all marks in your select.

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $series = Serie::find($id);
        $marks = Mark::all();
        return view('admin.series.edit', compact('series', 'marks'));
    }
```

Comment: Glad  i could help again :)  . Just one more thing, in your update function, you dont need the line ```$marks = Mark::find($id);``` you're not using it

Comment: Ok thank you I edit my code thank you very much chief.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, I am stuck for 2 days on a small problem. :-(

Comment: send me the link to your question, i will try to help :)

Comment: Thank you it's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201603/how-to-show-old-data-of-select-element/55201866#55201866

Comment: Here is url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201603/how-to-show-old-data-of-select-element/55201866#55201866