# How to show old data of select element

Tags: laravel

I am stuck for 2 days, do you know how to show old data of select element in Laravel?

```
<select name="sexe" id="sexe" class="form-control">
 <option value="">Choice</option>
 <option>Women</option>
 <option>Man</option>
 </select>
```

I have tried this but without success:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sexe">
   <option value="male" @if (old('sexe') == 'male') selected="selected" @endif>male</option>
   <option value="female" @if (old('sexe') == 'female') selected="selected" @endif>female</option>
</select>
```

My Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
        //
  $candidats = Candidat::find($id);
  $permis = Permis::all();
  return view('admin.candidats.edit', compact('candidats', 'permis'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $request->validate([
           'sexe' => 'required|string',
           'fk_permis' => 'required'
    ]);

      $candidats = Candidat::find($id);
      $candidats->sexe = $request->get('sexe');
      $candidats->fk_permis = $request->get('fk_permis');
      $candidats->save();
        return redirect()->route('candidats.index')
                    ->with('success', 'mise à jour effectuée');
    }
```

Edit:
1) **index.blade.php**

[image]

2) **edit.blade.php**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update function put  `withInput()`:

```
return redirect()->route('candidats.index')
                    ->with('success', 'mise à jour effectuée')->withInput();
```

In your select you can do this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sexe">
   <option value="male" @if (old('sexe') == 'male') selected="selected" @elseif($candidats->sexe == 'male') selected="selected" 
 @endif>male</option>
   <option value="female" @if (old('sexe') == 'female') selected="selected" @elseif($candidats->sexe == 'female') selected="selected" 
 @endif>female</option>
</select>
```

I loaded the selected option from your model here

`@elseif($candidats->sexe == 'male') selected="selected"`

So, if you saved 'male' in your `sexe` attribute this option will be selected.

Take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#old-input) for more info:

Comment: I always have the same problem. The item 1 is always by default... :-(

Comment: you're saving the correct option in your model?make sure when you click in the female option you save the female option in your model

Comment: I have edited my first message. (There are 2 screenshots) In my file index.blade the field 'sexe' is on 'female' when I click on the button edit, my dropdownlist shows the item 'man' instead of 'female' ... :-(

Comment: Waaaaww !! It works thank you a lot... :-) You are the best... Where did you learn Laravel???

Comment: You're welcome,friend .I learned by myself, i watched some videos, but none of them were good. What i do is practice a lot, read the documentation and help people when i can :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190180/discussion-between-lucas-piazzi-and-user11124425).

Answer (score 1):

If the old data was stored as a model, which I assume it was since this is a Laravel question and not a javascript question, you can use form-model binding to easily load the old data the next time you go to the page.

So, when you open your form, bind the model:

```
{{ Form::model($yourModel, array('route' => array('yourModel.update', $yourModel->id))) }}
```

And then within the select method, laravel (collective) can automatically make the old data the selected value.  Using the Laravel helper it might look like this:

```
{!! Form::select('sexe', $listOfYourNameAndIdForYourSelectItem, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'sexe']) !!}
```

By making the third argument `null`, as above, Laravel will make the model's old data the selected element.

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs) on the Laravel forms package for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you think my problem is in my Controller?  I have edited my first message...

Comment: Depends on how you set up the form.  If you want to take advantage of the simple Laravel binding as above, pass the `$candidats` model through to the view (possibly a new one on create (if you want) and the saved one on update, using the bind on update) and it will automatically make the selected item 'selected' using the format in my answer.